# How to access API from secured inctance from React app

Tags: reactjs, networking, google-cloud-platform

I have two instances on Google Cloud Platform (GCP), one with the frontend React app, another with Spring backend. The second instance allows ingress traffic from the frontend instance. Curl from frontend to that instance works correctly, but when I open frontend in my browser requests to my backend fails due to connection timeout. How to determine the problem and fix this. Instances running on GCP.

Comment: Hi there! If you frontend can reach your backend using CURL but on your browser you get an error, maybe what is wrong is your APP and how your APP make the calls to your backend. What do you get when you inspect your app using [Google Chrome Console for Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console). Please, add more information about the error.

Comment: Could you please share the error logs from Stackdriver Logging? Are you using App Engine? If yes , are you using Standard or Flexible environment?